# Unsupported top level event type "topTouchStart" dispatched when upgrade to expo 24.0.0

Tags: react-native

I'm creating a simple react-native project, but it unexpected run into errors when I upgrade **expo** to version `24.0.0`.

[image]

**app.json**:

```
{
  "name": "TipCalculator",
  "displayName": "rn_tip_calculator",
  "expo": {
      "name": "TipCalculator",
      "slug": "rn-tip-calculator",
      "sdkVersion": "24.0.0"
    }
}
```

**package.json**:

```
{
  "name": "rn_tip_calculator",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "author": "GeniusDoan <nhoxbypass@gmail.com> (https://github.com/nhoxbypass)",
  "repository": "https://github.com/HCMUS-IceTeaViet-SE/rn_tip_calculator",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "^24.0.0",
    "react": "^16.0.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-24.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-deprecated-custom-components": "^0.1.0",
    "react-native-i18n": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-segmented-control-tab": "^3.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "19.0.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "1.9.1",
    "jest": "19.0.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.0.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

This is known-issue in November 2017, I've read many Github issues about it. It happens with `react-native v50.0`.

But in my project I'm using the latest react-native version `v51.0`, but it STILL NOT working. I'm running my app on Android 6.0.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: I've got the same issue

Comment: @imalik8088 did you find out how to fix it?

Comment: I still have unfortunately the error, did u have find solution for that?

Comment: @imalik8088 no, I eject my project to normal react-native init :(

Answer (score 4):

This issues seems to be a React Native bug, which is has been discussed here with temporarily solution described here.

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/16522#issuecomment-345513116

Comment: thanks for answering my question, so where I must put the code?

Answer (score 0):

Expo SDK 26 still an issue as per the description above this comment that is many characters long

Comment: I decided to get rid of expo since then : (